# Linq to entities rolling 12 month data query

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a requirement where i need to display Rolling 12 month data.Below is my query

```
 var lt = (from a in apps
    select new
    {
     AppId = a.Id,
     AppName = a.Name,
    DataPoints = (from e in errs join ei in errInstances on e.Id equals ei.ErrorId
    where (e.ApplicationId == a.Id && ei.stampUTC >= startDate && ei.stampUTC <= endDate)
    group ei by new { ei.stampUTC.Month, ei.stampUTC.Year } into grp
    select new { Year = grp.Key.Year, Month = grp.Key.Month, Count = grp.Count() }).OrderBy(y => y.Year)    }).ToArray();
```

I need data in the fom 
AppId,AppName,DataPoints= {data of all 12 months}
in case for a month there is no data for an app..then the month should come with count as 0.But my query gives me only the months for which app data exists

For example an app has data for only dec 2011..then i need the datapoints to hold 0 s for jan 2011 to nov 2011 and count of dec 2011..But my present query gives Datapoints to hold only dec 2011 data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are doing a filter on a date range in your data point selection, which means you won't get any data points for values outside of that range.  If you were doing this directly in SQL, you would have to use a table variable (or some other temp table or collection of date ranges), and then do a left join on that to your errors to get a list that contains nulls on the right side of your join.  I am going to assume you don't have a table in SQL you are maintaining to do a join on.  If not, here is what I would suggest trying (it isn't very efficient, but it solves your problem):

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var beginningOfCurrentMonth = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(today.Day - 1));
// get list of previous 12 month date ranges
var dateRanges = new List<List<DateTime>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    dateRanges.Add(new List<DateTime>() { today.AddMonths(-i), today.AddMonths(-i + 1) });
// get your apps
var appList = from a in apps
                select new
                {
                    AppId = a.Id,
                    AppName = a.Name
                }.ToList();
// get final list by looping through each app...
var finalList = appList.Select(app => new
{
    AppId = app.AppId,
    AppName = app.AppName,
    // and then loop through each date range value and do a select to get data poitn information.
    DataPoints = dateRanges.Select(dateRange =>
    (from e in errs
        join ei in errInstances on e.Id equals ei.ErrorId
        where (e.ApplicationId == app.AppId && ei.stampUTC >= dateRange[0] && ei.stampUTC < dateRange[1])
        group ei by new { ei.stampUTC.Month, ei.stampUTC.Year } into grp
        select new { Year = grp.Key.Year, Month = grp.Key.Month, Count = grp.Count() })
        )
});
```

I didn't test this since I don't have your data entities, so I apologize if I have some typing errors.

Comment: I've tried this approach....It has a problem that we are trying to compare a date field from database with an in memory date field...Linq doesn't allow it...Finally i've decide to do it using a stored proc which was way simpler..Thanks for ur answer